# How to pass a with query as a parameter to a PL/pgSQL function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

`F(aTable TEXT)` is a PL/pgSQL function, which use a table as parameter. When I call this function like this:

`with w as (
    ...
)
select * from F('w')`

It return an error: w not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`w` in your query is the name of a derived table (the "common table" produced from the [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html)). This is a special kind of temporary table visible exclusively in the DML command the CTE is attached to - unlike regular tables (visible globally) or temporary tables (visible inside the same session), there are **no entries in the system catalogs** for `w`. You can also not create indexes for it or modify it in any way.

The function `F` takes a `text` parameter. You kept the function definition a secret, but it probably runs dynamic SQL with [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) inside. `w` is not visible inside `EXECUTE`, so there is no way to do this.

Create a **temporary table** instead.

Or better yet, integrate the whole query, including code from the function. This is typically fastest.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have learned. At last I use all code in the `w` as a parameter. I couldn't include code from the function, because the function will be used in many places.